# Android Contact API

Tags: android

I have used all the contact examples in my Android emulator, but it is not displaying the phone numbers.
It only displays names, so can anyone give me an example of the Android contacts API which imports names and numbers from the phonebook?

Comment: It depends on which version of Android you are developing for and what device your testing on.

Answer (score 0):

[Here is a sample project](http://github.com/commonsguy/cw-advandroid/tree/master/Contacts/Spinners/) showing access the contacts' names and phone numbers via both the 1.x and 2.x version of the Android contacts content provider.